# Facebook PHP SDK Graph API - is it possible to access PAST events?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-events

I can access the events info for a page.

```
$events = $facebook->api('myPage/events?access_token=mytokenhere');
```

I've tried:

```
$events = $facebook->api('myPage/pe?access_token=mytokenhere');
```

Which seemed the obvious choice but it returns a fatal.

I cannot find any mention of PAST events in the 'documentation'.
Does this mean it is not (currently) possible?

Comment: Using undocumented connection of `page` doesn't look obvious. Where did you get info that you can use `pe` for access past events? It's also good to know what exactly you mean by saying "past events" (`end_time` field of `event` isn't required)?

Comment: I didn't that's kind of the point of the question isn't it? How do I access past events or is it not possible? The API states each graph object is accessed using the uri on the page containing the data, "events" is the uri for events and using "events" with the graph API works - "pe" is uri for past events but doesn't work - hence the question.

Comment: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/ states "All objects in Facebook can be accessed in the same way:" By "ALL" do them mean "some"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the "events" object returns all events as opposed the actual events page which only shows current ones, yes very inconsistent! The good news is you should be able to manipulate the returned data to separate current and past events using a timestamp in your php.

Comment: No probs. It was a perfectly straight forward question especially given what the Fb documentation says on the page you pointed out. Why would anyone "vote" it down, there are too many little Hitlers on here.